# HTML5 - Playing a movie in reverse

Tags: javascript, html, video, reverse

I'm trying to reproduce the effect that Apple did in macbook pro site (https://www.apple.com/br/mac-pro/) running a movie in reverse.

I found a script in jsFiddle, which apparently runs perfectly. But works only with video from Apple, with my video(exported directaly from After Effects) does not work, skipping parts of the video.

Can anyone tell me if there is a specific video codec for this purpose?

Thank you in advance

**Jsfiddle links:**

*Using apple video - http://jsfiddle.net/h9EVQ/419/*

*Using my video - http://jsfiddle.net/h9EVQ/418/*

The code:

```
intervalRewind = setInterval(function(){
       video.playbackRate = 1.0;
       if(video.currentTime == 0){
           clearInterval(intervalRewind);
           video.pause();
       }
       else{
           video.currentTime += -.1;
       }
},30);
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong except that its jumpy and that's because of your videos frame positions of product. Also you can simply change this `video.currentTime += -.1;` to `video.currentTime -=  .1;`  also play with the interval request. Also `setInterval` isn't the best method a recursive `setTimeout` is better.

Comment: Rewinding your video works fine for me. Safari 8.0.3 on a Mac

Comment: Seems to be working, what do you mean by "does not work"? Be more clear exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry! My problem is that the video does not play smooth, skipping parts of the video. Running Chrome

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the different programs are outputting videos with different amounts of keyframes, can you compare the amount of keyframes for the video that works to the one that doesn't?

Comment: You mean the Frame rate?

Comment: Take a look: rumba.com.br/temp/brastemp/halley/download/video_report.jpg

Comment: Framerate is the number of frames per second on playback, keyframes deals with how frames are grouped and often has an impact on how far ahead you can skip in a video. Since keyframes are additional information, more of them means more file size and more quality. I'm thinking that the video doesn't have enough keyframes when it comes out of the other program and so is skippy when you play it backwards.

Comment: Some possible links to help explain: http://superuser.com/questions/587706/what-are-levels-and-keyframe-distance-when-rendering-video-in-adobe-premiere  and  http://philipbloom.net/forum/threads/keyframe-settings-for-encoding-h-264.11330/  it appears that video_report doesn't contain keyframe information.

Comment: Seems from the examples that the stuttering happens more while the video is loading, if I wait until the full video has loaded the playback is smooth, in chrome and safari on desktop.